# Preserving String format when passing only one of the required parameters

Tags: ios, swift, string, url, format

I've got a URL format stored like this in a String:

```
"https://website.com/something/%s/else/%s"
```

I would like to add the first String whilst preserving the format. However when I create a string passing only the first parameter and the format the resulting string has a `null` value instead of the second `%s`.

```
String(format: "https://website.com/something/%s/else/%s", "param1Asutfstring")
```

Results in:

```
https://website.com/something/param1Asutfstring/else/(null)
```

I do wonder whether there is a way to do so whilst preserving the second `%s`.

```
https://website.com/something/param1Asutfstring/else/%s
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

I need something that given this:

```
String(format: "https://website.com/something/%s/else/%s", "param1Asutfstring")
```

Returns a string in exactly this format:

```
"https://website.com/something/param1Asutfstring/else/%s"
```

Comment: I wonder that this works at all, the format for (NS)String is `%@`, not `%s` – Anyway, you can pass `%s` as the second string.

Comment: If the format has 2 placeholders then you *must* pass 2 parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `%s` in the second parameter:

```
let url = String(format: "https://website.com/something/%@/else/%@", "param1Asutfstring", "%s")
print(url)
```

Note that `%@` is used because `%s` doesn't work (for me at least)

Output:

```
https://website.com/something/param1Asutfstring/else/%s
```